Any way to go a step further from Deutsch algorithm and calculate the results of f(x) in parallel?
Deutsch-Josza algorithm, as a demonstration of the parallel computing power of quantum computing, calculates in one operation both values of a $(0,1) \mapsto (0,1)$ function $f(x)$. But it only concludes whether $f(x)$ is constant or balanced. With the parallel computing power of quantum computing, I'd think it's possible to conclude both values of $f(0)$ and $f(1)$, which may be one of the four possible outcomes: $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, and $(1,1)$. Is there a quantum algorithm doing this? Or is there a proof saying it is impossible?
